# RSA. Plaintext is given in string, how to convert that to an integer?

Tags: type-conversion, rsa

let's say I have RSA and the input with "one" or maybe "two", and I would like to run RSA on that to obtain the ciphertext. Does anyone know how to convert those strings into an integer that I attempt to run RSA on?

Comment: [See here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#section-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular instances, we were asked to used 0-25 as A-Z.

so "ONE" would be "141304"